Isn't this an example of zero padding increasing ability to resolve peaks?
I've always heard that zero padding doesn't really increase frequency resolution, it just allows us to get more accurate amplitudes of peaks by increasing the likelihood that a DFT bin will be close enough to the true frequency of a signal (Why do we say that "zero-padding doesn't really increase frequency resolution").
If the frequency resolution is $1/T$, I'm assuming that means we shouldn't be able to resolve two peaks with $\Delta f < 1/T$, no matter how much we zero pad. But then what's going on in the generated plot here? I have 50Hz and 50.9Hz sine waves (sampled at 1000Hz), with $1/T=1 > 0.9 = \Delta f$ and, and sure enough, the two peaks aren't resolvable in the non-padded spectrum. But the (4x) zero padded version clearly shows two peaks. In the linked post above, an answer says that "If one's requirement1 for resolution requires a dip (for instance a minimum 3 dB lowering) between spectral peaks, then the resolution will be even lower than the FFT bin spacing." But there's much more than a 3dB dip in between peaks here!
Am I misunderstanding something or is there a problem with my code?
[]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a signal with two very closely spaced frequencies
fs = 1000  # Sampling frequency
T = 1  # Signal duration (1 second)
t = np.linspace(0, T, int(fs * T), endpoint=False)  # Time vector

# Two frequencies, separated by less than 1/T
f1 = 50
f2 = 50.9
A = 1
signal = A*np.sin(2 * np.pi * f1 * t) + A*np.sin(2 * np.pi * f2 * t)

# Perform FFT without zero padding
fft_no_padding = np.fft.fft(signal)
freq_no_padding = np.fft.fftfreq(len(signal), d=1/fs)
spectrum_no_padding_dB = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fft_no_padding) + 1e-12)  # Convert to dB

# Perform FFT with zero padding (4x the original length)
zero_padding_factor = 4
zero_padded_signal = np.pad(signal, (0, (zero_padding_factor - 1) * len(signal)), 'constant')
fft_zero_padded = np.fft.fft(zero_padded_signal)
freq_zero_padded = np.fft.fftfreq(len(zero_padded_signal), d=1/fs)
spectrum_zero_padded_dB = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fft_zero_padded) + 1e-12)  # Convert to dB

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Spectrum without zero padding
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(freq_no_padding[:len(freq_no_padding)//2], spectrum_no_padding_dB[:len(freq_no_padding)//2], label="No Padding")
plt.title("Spectrum Without Zero Padding")
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Magnitude (dB)")
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

# Spectrum with zero padding
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(freq_zero_padded[:len(freq_zero_padded)//2], spectrum_zero_padded_dB[:len(freq_zero_padded)//2], label="With Zero Padding", color="orange")
plt.title("Spectrum With Zero Padding")
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Magnitude (dB)")
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


The frequency resolution of the DFT is $\Delta f = \frac{f_s}{N}$ where $f_s$ is the sample rate and $N$ the FFT length. For $N=4000$ and $f_s = 1000Hz$ the frequency resolution is 0.25Hz so of course you can resolve 0.9Hz.

This brings up an interesting point about what we mean when we say "resolution" of the DFT. It is possible, if the signals are spaced sufficiently close to $\frac{f_{s}}{N}$ (in your case they are spaced $0.9\frac{f_{s}}{N}$), to determine that there are two frequencies present. However, this doesn't mean that these signals are fully "resolved". While there is a strong correlation between these two concepts, they are not the same. Resolution has to do with the broadness of the peaks in the spectrum. The spectrum from a DFT can be thought of as being the convolution of an infinite length sinusoid with a Dirichlet kernel
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}S(\psi)W_{R}(\omega-\psi)d\psi
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
W_{R}(\omega) = \frac{\sin\left[\left(N-\frac{1}{2}\right)\omega\right]}{\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}
The first nulls of $W_{R}(\omega)$ occur at $\pm \frac{2\pi}{N}$. So, if we have a two frequencies that are spaced less than $\pm\frac{f_{s}}{N}$, these signals will not be fully "resolved" as they are spaced less than one null away from each other. Notice, if we further increase the size of our FFT, there is no change in the "broadness" of the peaks.

Notice what happens when we move the second frequency to 51 Hz.

There is now a null between the two signals, which means our signals are fully resolved! Now let's observe what happens if we move the second frequency to 50.6 Hz.

Notice, there is no extra separability that is obtained by significantly oversampling our FFT! This shows that the FFT size doesn't affect resolution, only the number of non-zero data points in our signal being FFT'd.
So, in summary, while "resolution" is correlated with "ability to tell if more than one signal is present", they are not exactly the same. The former has a definition related to the bandwidth of the signal being FFT'd, where as the latter is an empirical observation.

Note, $N$ is the number of non-zero coefficients in our signal, not the number of FFT points. We window our signal prior to zero-padding and FFTing, not after.

Two questions: 1. Why is the limit of our ability to "resolve" two signals determined by the presence/absence of a null between the two frequencies? I have a vague intuition that if the frequencies are closer than the width of the main lobe of the kernel than they would be blurred together, but I can't pinpoint exactly why that would be. 2. Can you expand on how "resolution" has to do with the broadness of peaks in the spectrum? I see that in all three cases, the broadness doesn't change with extra zero padding, but I'm not sure what that's showing. What's the significance of broadness?

@empty-inch to the first question, it’s related to the Dirichlet kernel, and how a delta function in the DTFT will be spread out by a finite sample approximation. As to the second question, the broadness of the peak represents the ambiguity in the true frequency present. A broad peak means that there is less ability to distinguish the true frequency since there is a more gradual rolloff in power compared to a narrow peak.

Thanks! I still feel like I'm missing something though. In your last plot, you concluded that since the two peaks don't visually separate regardless of the degree of zero padding, this shows that resolution doesn't increase with more zero padding. But my post was an example of two peaks which DO separate with more zero padding, and I thought that the whole point of your answer was that visual separation == resolution. Also, is there a qualitative difference between your first two plots that I'm missing? There's only a Dirichlet kernel null in the second, but what do the plots show?

@empty-inch the point I was trying to make with the last plot is that, if zero-padding did in fact increase resolution, then we should see a null at least start to form when we significantly zero-pad, but we don’t. Zero-padding can improve visual separability, but as the first plot shows it’s only up to a certain point. After that you’re just taking unnecessarily large FFTs. If it did continually increase separability, eventually a null would form, giving you better resolution.

Let's look on the definition of the DFT $$X(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{N}}$$
where $x(n)$ is a discrete signal with $N$ samples.
The frequency (bin) resolution of the DFT is given by $\Delta f = \frac{f_{s}}{N}$ where $f_{s}$ is the sampling frequency.
For example let's take $f_{s}=1000Hz$ and $N=f_{s}\cdot T=1000$ so the bin resolution is $\Delta f=\frac{f_{s}}{N}=1Hz$ and each bin in the plot shows as the frequency content of the signal in a $1Hz$ bin.
If we will zero pad the signal we will get $N_{padded}=4\cdot N=4000$ and the bin resolution will be $\Delta f=\frac{f_{s}}{N_{padded}}=0.25Hz$ so now we are seeing in each bin $0.25Hz$ of the frequency content and the number of bins increased.
This is why you are able to distinguish between two peaks that have $0.9Hz$ between them.

The frequency resolution isn't related to the number of FFT points, but only the number of non-zero coefficients in our signal being FFT'd.

I call $\frac{f_s}{N}$ where $N$ is, like @baddioes said, the number of non-zero coefficients, the resolution and $\frac{f_s}{M}$ where $M = N +$ the number of $0$s padded the precision

@Jdip Would zeros in the middle of a signal (not appended, e.g. a sine wave whose frequency is such that its zero crossings fall right at sample points) count as non-zero coefficients? Or is this a situation where we sweep that under the rug since the real-life probability of having a measurement of a signal that's exactly 0 is a measure zero event?

@empty-inch non-zero coefficients is probably not exactly the best term. It would be more like “zero-information” coefficients. Zero-padding doesn’t increase the support of the sampled function.
